# Stop Camel after too many retries

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to implement more advanced Apache Camel error handling: 
in case if there are too many pending retries then stop processing at all and log all collected exceptions somewhere.

First part (stop on too many retries) is already implemented by following helper method, that gets size of retry queue and I just stop context if queue is over some limit:

```
    static Long getToRetryTaskCount(CamelContext context)   {
    Long retryTaskCount = null;
    ScheduledExecutorService errorHandlerExecutor = context.getErrorHandlerExecutorService();


    if (errorHandlerExecutor instanceof SizedScheduledExecutorService)
    {
        SizedScheduledExecutorService svc = (SizedScheduledExecutorService) errorHandlerExecutor;
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = svc.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor();
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = executor.getQueue();
        retryTaskCount = (long) queue.size();           
    }
    return retryTaskCount;
}
```

But this code smells to me and I don't like it and also I don't see here any way to collect the exceptions caused all this retries.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a new control bus component in camel 2.11 which could do what you want ([source](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html))

```
template.sendBody("controlbus:route?routeId=foo&action=stop", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to shutdown the CamelContext, just the route in question...that way the rest of your app can still function, you can get route stats and view/move messages to alternate queues, etc.

see https://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html